# Convert list in python

Tags: python

Hi everyone I have a json

```
[{"seller_id": 3, "item": {"product_id": 4, "amount": 1, "id": 9}},
 {"seller_id": 1, "item": {"product_id": 1 , "amount": 2, "id": 10}},
 {"seller_id": 3, "item": {"product_id": 3, "amount": 2, "id": 11}},
 {"seller_id ": 1," item ": {" product_id ": 2," amount ": 2," id ": 12}}]
```

I want to group together that means identical sellers will group the item again

returned results are like:

```
[{"seller_id": 3, "list_item": [{"product_id": 4, "amount": 1, "id": 9},
 {"product_id": 3, "amount": 2, "id": 11}]},
 {"seller_id": 1, "list_item": [{"product_id": 1, "amount": 2, "id": 10},
 {"product_id": 1, "amount": 2, "id": 10}, {"product_id": 2, "amount": 2, "id": 12}]}]
```

Who has the idea?

Comment: Your json example has excess spaces around some of the labels, e.g. `"seller_id "` and `" amount "` instead of `"seller_id"` and `"amount"` - is that intentional and part of the problem?

Comment: There is `itertools.groupby`, which would solve your problem. First sort by seller_id then groupby on seller_id.

Comment: What code have you used so far? there are many examples out there that do what you're asking.

Comment: this not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    {"seller_id": 3, "item": {"product_id": 4, "amount": 1, "id": 9}},
    {"seller_id": 1, "item": {"product_id": 1, "amount": 2, "id": 10}},
    {"seller_id": 3, "item": {"product_id": 3, "amount": 2, "id": 11}},
    {"seller_id": 1, "item": {"product_id": 2, "amount": 2, "id": 12}}
]

grouped = defaultdict(list)
flattened = []

for item in data:
    grouped[item['seller_id']].append(item['item'])

for k, v in grouped.items():
    flattened.append({'seller_id': k, 'list_item': v})

print(flattened)
```

Another option is to use `defaultdict` and then flatten it with the necessary format.

Does not require preliminary sorting.

Comment: defaultdicts are explained in the docs [8.3. collections — Container datatypes](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 4):

Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (and assuming that the weird spacing around some of the keys and values are accidental):

```
from itertools import groupby
values = [{"seller_id": 3, "item": {"product_id": 4, "amount": 1, "id": 9}},
          {"seller_id": 1, "item": {"product_id": 1, "amount": 2, "id": 10}},
          {"seller_id": 3, "item": {"product_id": 3, "amount": 2, "id": 11}},
          {"seller_id": 1, "item": {"product_id": 2, "amount": 2, "id": 12}}]

def get_seller_id(d):
    return d['seller_id']

groups = []
for seller_id, items in groupby(sorted(values, key=get_seller_id), get_seller_id):
    groups.append({'seller_id': seller_id, 'list_item': list(items)})

print(groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that builds a dictionary and then flattens it into the format you want and a second solution that does the whole thing in one comprehension.

```
from collections import defaultdict

catalog = [
    {"seller_id": 3, "item": {"product_id": 4, "amount": 1, "id": 9}},
    {"seller_id": 1, "item": {"product_id": 1, "amount": 2, "id": 10}},
    {"seller_id": 3, "item": {"product_id": 3, "amount": 2, "id": 11}},
    {"seller_id": 1, "item": {"product_id": 2, "amount": 2, "id": 12}}
]

new_catalog = defaultdict(list)
for entry in catalog:
    new_catalog[entry["seller_id"]].append(entry["item"])

result = [{"seller_id": i, "list_item": l} for i, l in new_catalog.items()]

print(result)

direct = [{"seller_id": i, "list_item": [c["item"] for c in catalog if c["seller_id"] == i]}
          for i in set([c["seller_id"] for c in catalog])]

print(direct)
```

Edit: changed the manual construction of an empty dictionary and adding new elements to using defaultdict(list) instead, since this does exactly what is required.

Comment: Class `defaultdict` is useful in this situation to avoid the need to explicitly test if key is already present.